# How to get directory content with Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I try to get all files (names) form the directory. I use `Node.js` + `Express`. Here is my Express code:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var filePath = path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'), '/public/images/');
    var directoryContent = [];
    getDirectoryContent(filePath, directoryContent);
    res.send(directoryContent);
});

function getDirectoryContent(dir, arr) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function (err, flist) {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }
        var elemNum = 0;
        var processEntry = function (entry) {
            arr.push(entry);
            //console.log(entry);
        };
        var dirIterator = function () {
            processEntry(flist[elemNum]);
            elemNum++;
            if (elemNum < flist.length) {
                process.nextTick(dirIterator);
            }
        };
        if (elemNum < flist.length) {
            process.nextTick(dirIterator);
        }
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

But the result is [] - empty array. What I'm doing wrong?

PS

Seams that the problem is in callback mechanism. Bit I can be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not respecting the asynchronous nature of that directory-reading operation. The `fs.readdir` is async and will "eventually" cause your handling function to be called, so you're going to have to tell Node.js that it needs to resume its work when that happens:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var imagePath = path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'), '/public/images/');

function getDirectoryContent(req, res, next) {
  fs.readdir(imagePath , function (err, images) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.locals.filenames = images;
    next();
  });
}

router.get('/', getDirectoryContent, function(req, res) {
  // build a response using res.locals.filenames here.
  // just sending the names is silly, and so for demonstration only
  res.send(res.locals.filenames);
});

module.exports = router;
```

1. you can capture the path once. It's never going to change.
2. make the function to get that dir listing a proper middleware function: req/res/next go in, next(err) is called when things go wrong, next() is called when things go right

   1. things go wrong when reading the dir goes wrong
   2. things go right when we can read the dir. The API tells us the 'result' is an array of filenames. We store those on `res.locals`, and then tell express to move on to the next middleware function in the route.
3. when we reach our last function (in this case in a glorious chain of two functions, but in a real app that chain can easy be 10 or more operations with one function per operation) we generate a result using `res.locals.filenames`, which we know exists, because otherwise we wouldn't have reached this part of the route handling, a next(err) would have occured and express would have moved us to our error handler instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `fs.readdir` method is an asynchronous operation. You will actually have to pass a callback function to that method and wait for the operation to be executed.

Right now it is empty because you flush the response before the operation is finished.

You can either use `fs.readdirSync` witch is an synchronous operation. The result is an Array of files, if any. If an Error occurs it will be thrown, so you need to catch the Error inside your function.

```js
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var filePath = path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'), '/public/images/');
  
    try {
       var directoryContent = fs.readdirSync(filePath);
      res.send(directoryContent);
    } catch(e) {
      next(e);
    }
   
});
```

Or use the same method, but now wait for the result before flushing the response.

```js
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var filePath = path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'), '/public/images/');
    
    fs.readdir(dir, function (err, flist) {
      if(err) return next(err);
      
      res.send(flist);
    });
    
});
```